# Why is Scala Option waiting for AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject

Tags: scala, profiling, java.util.concurrent, jprofiler

I'm making Scala function more parallel so it can be called from multiple threads and really run in parallel. I'm using profiler and I see that my function `compute` is waiting for 388 ms for `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject`.
According to the profiler waiting happens in `scala.Option.filter`.

I tried to look at the bytecode by `javap` but I don't see any `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer`.

I'm running my code with `ExecutorService`:

```scala
  { (1 to 24) ++ (24 to 1 by -1) }.foreach { threads =>

    val executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads)

    compute(executorService, s"Threads $threads")

    executorService.shutdown()
    executorService.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
  }
```

I expect no waiting and no `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer`. Where does `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer` come from?

Comment: That's likely a queue used by the ExecutorService to queue jobs; not a part of `Option`.

Comment: @Carcigenicate you're right, I was confused by stacktrace from JProfiler but it seems that the stacktrace in the profiler is only some approximation (for performance reasons they don't get stacktraces from JVM).

Answer (score 0):

`public abstract class java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer extends java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractOwnableSynchronizer implements java.io.Serializable`

it is coming from Java concurrent library and involved when concurrent code in run-time.